taskbar MinWidth for win11
For win10 I can set the MinWidth for icons/labels on taskbar by Regedit in
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics

but I found it does not work with win11, is there any possible new solution for win11?
update:
os version is 23H2 and 22631.4317
